# Каим образом извлечь значени полей из ассоциативного массива и добавить их в одномерый массив

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Выборка из бд, которая возвращает объект

```
 $result = DB::table('messages')->select('mess_to','mess_from')->where('mess_to', '=', $id)->where('mess_from', '=', $goid)->orWhere(function($query) use ($id,$goid) {

              $query->where('mess_to', '=',$goid )
                      ->where('mess_from', '=', $id);
        })
        ->get();
```

Возвращает вот что

```
Collection {#265 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#261 ▶}
    1 => {#263 ▶}
    2 => {#264 ▶}
    3 => {#266 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Далее переводим возвращаемый объект в массив

```
$result = (array)$result;
```

Результат такой

```
array:1 [▼
  "\x00*\x00items" => array:4 [▼
    0 => {#261 ▼
      +"mess_to": "31"
      +"mess_from": "13"
    }
    1 => {#263 ▼
      +"mess_to": "13"
      +"mess_from": "31"
    }
    2 => {#264 ▼
      +"mess_to": "31"
      +"mess_from": "13"
    }
    3 => {#266 ▼
      +"mess_to": "13"
      +"mess_from": "31"
    }
  ]
]
 Мне нужно для выбрачить числа из этого массива и поместить их в одномерный мсассив, как это сделать?
```

Comment: `$result = (array)$result;` — зачем это?))

Comment: На мой взгляд, так проще извелчиь данные, но возможно я шибаюсь. Можно ли извлечь данные из объекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $result = DB::table('messages')->select('mess_to','mess_from')->where('mess_to', '=', $id)->where('mess_from', '=', $goid)->orWhere(function($query) use ($id,$goid) {

          $query->where('mess_to', '=',$goid )
                  ->where('mess_from', '=', $id);
    })
    ->get();

    $se = array();

  foreach ($result as $v){
 $se[] = $v->mess_from;
 $se[] = $v->mess_to;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что в $result у вас 3 объекта, в каждом есть id, name, surname. Пилим следующее:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {
// Тут делаем что угодно с каждым объектом, там выводим к примеру
echo $result[$i]['id']; // Выведет id объекта в цикле
}
```

То есть вывод будет

```
1
2
3
```

Если будет более детальнее описано условие, будет более детальный ответ, но это то, что вам нужно

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74785/discussion-on-answer-by-paul-wall-------).